# get JSON from long string

Tags: php

Since my host doesn't allow `file_get_contents` I must use something else to do an API call.
I got this code to get the content of a website:

```
function get_contents_by_uri($uri) {
$uriElem = parse_url ( $uri );
$fp = @fsockopen ( $uriElem ['host'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 10 );

if (! $fp) {
    throw new Exception ( "Could not create socket: '" . $errnstr . "' (" . $errno . ")." );
}

$request = "GET " . $uriElem ['path'] . (isset ( $uriElem ['query'] ) ? "?" . $uriElem ['query'] : "") . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$request .= "Host: " . $uriElem ['host'] . "\r\n";
$request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

fwrite ( $fp, $request );
$response = "";
while ( ! feof ( $fp ) ) {
    $response .= fgets ( $fp, 128 );
}
fclose ( $fp );

// split headers from data
$responseSplit = explode ( "\r\n\r\n", $response, 2 );

return $responseSplit [1];
}
```

This works fine for this simple call:
http://dogechain.info/chain/Dogecoin/q/getblockcount

But it adds some data to calls containing JSON.

Example:

If I use `get_contents_by_uri()` on http://data.bter.com/api/1/ticker/doge_btc, I don't get

```
{"result":"true","last":"0.00000188","high":"0.00000191","low":"0.00000185","avg":"0.00000188","sell":"0.00000189","buy":"0.00000188","vol_doge":82094227.628,"vol_btc":154.34039658}
```

but

```
b6 {"result":"true","last":"0.00000188","high":"0.00000191","low":"0.00000185","avg":"0.00000188","sell":"0.00000189","buy":"0.00000188","vol_doge":82094227.628,"vol_btc":154.34039658} 0
```

How do I get the sole JSON part of this string?

Comment: json's just a string. if the `b6[space]` part is constant, then a simple `substr()` call can strip it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why (so far), but using `HTTP/1.0` instead of `HTTP/1.1` works for me.
(I found it by lurking Internet and trying other solutions.)

Comment: how do i use HTTP/1.0? I´m a newbie to php :D

Comment: Just change it in first line of `$request` parameters - there is `HTTP/1.1` at the end, put there `HTTP/1.0` instead.